# Android KSoap2 Response from server array is empty

Tags: android, arrays, post, response, ksoap2

I have searched a lot but didn't find any kind of help, so am hoping someone could shed some light on the matter.

I want to send an array using KSoap and I do this as follows:

First I construct the soap object like this:

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(GENERICNAMESPACE, SOAP_METHOD_NAME);

PropertyInfo attr = new PropertyInfo();
        attr.name = "patientLogin";
        attr.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
        attr.namespace = GENERICNAMESPACE;
        attr.setValue(patientId);
        request.addProperty(attr);

        //could be patientPassword
        attr = new PropertyInfo();
        attr.name = "passwd";
        attr.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
        attr.namespace = GENERICNAMESPACE;
        attr.setValue(patientPassword);
        request.addProperty(attr);

        Vector vectorOfIDsRead = new Vector();
        vectorOfIDsRead.addElement(idsRead);

        attr = new PropertyInfo();
        attr.name = "IDsRead";
        attr.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
        attr.namespace = GENERICNAMESPACE;
        attr.setValue(vectorOfIDsRead);
        request.addProperty(attr);

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER10);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(GENERICURL);
        androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call(GENERICSOAP_ACTION_URL+"feedbackRead", envelope);

            SoapPrimitive resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapPrimitive) envelope
                    .getResponse();

            //log request
            Log.e("SendFeedbackRead", "/////////////////////RequestDump////////////////////");
            Log.e("SendFeedbackRead", androidHttpTransport.requestDump.toString());     
            Log.e("SendFeedbackRead", "/////////////////////////////////////////");

            //log request
            Log.e("SendFeedbackRead", "///////////////////ResponseDump/////////////////");
            Log.e("SendFeedbackRead", androidHttpTransport.responseDump.toString());        
            Log.e("SendFeedbackRead", "/////////////////////////////////////////");

            Log.e("FeedbackRead",
                    "FeedbackRead : " + resultsRequestSOAP.toString());

            return resultsRequestSOAP.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("FeedbackRead", "SENDFEEDBACKREAD : " + e);
            return e.getMessage();
        }
```

The request dump reveals that I am sending:

```
<v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><v:Header />
<v:Body>
<n0:feedbackRead id="o0" c:root="1" xmlns:n0="http://testing.starburst.com/GenericWS">
<n0:patientLogin i:type="d:string">patient1</n0:patientLogin>
<n0:passwd i:type="d:string">pat1</n0:passwd>
<n0:IDsRead i:type="c:Array" c:arrayType="d:anyType[1]"><item i:type="d:string">1234test</item></n0:IDsRead></n0:feedbackRead>
</v:Body>
</v:Envelope>
```

But the response I get states that the list is empty.

feedbackRead, empty submitted ID list!

It is not as it has one value.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think your error is here:

```
Vector vectorOfIDsRead = new Vector();
vectorOfIDsRead.addElement(idsRead);
attr = new PropertyInfo();
attr.name = "IDsRead";
attr.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
attr.namespace = GENERICNAMESPACE;
attr.setValue(vectorOfIDsRead);
request.addProperty(attr);
```

You declare `vectorOfIDsRead` as a `Vector` but you put the type as a `STRING_CLASS`.
It would be:

```
attr.setType(vectorOfIDsRead.getClass());
```

And then :

```
... create the envelope ...
envelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "IDsRead", new Vector().getClass());
```

Hope it helps. Also take a look at this: http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/CodingTipsAndTricks#sending/receiving_array_of_complex_types_or_primitives

EDIT: Anyway, could you put the method signature of your SOAP_METHOD_NAME?

Comment: Thanks for your input. I tried to change the differences that you made in my code but that did not help then I followed the tutorial. Again, no result. The method name is SOAP_METHOD_NAME = "feedbackRead".

Comment: Why does this error occur? To me it is evident that the vector is not empty. What are the reasons for the server not seeing that? The response has been changed to show what the id list is as per the server: 04-03 19:22:17.082: E/SendFeedbackRead(18129): <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><feedbackRead_Response xmlns="http://depressix.inescporto.pt/GenericWS"><feedbackRead_Result>feedbackRead, empty submitted ID list!&#xD;
it has these values &#xD; which is not the id list. I think the answer to my problem lies there.

Comment: By method signature I mean the number and types of parameters of "feedbackRead" method. (Sorry for my English). I don't know other way to pass an array.